# Why can't I assign a retrieved document to variable in console

Tags: javascript, meteor

Just learning Meteor and wrapping my head around javascript at the same time.

I have a collection defined and was able to successfully retrieve a document via the console command using a .findOne():

```
myCollection.findOne({elementID: "avatar"});
```

however, when I find and assign it to a variable at the same time it returns undefined:

```
var elementObject = myCollection.findOne({elementID: "avatar"});
```

**Edit:** After `var elementObject = myCollection.findOne({elementID: "avatar"});` returns `undefined`, I ran `elementObject` again in the console and it returns the right value. So in the end it works but not displaying it on the first try. It'll be good to understand why.

Comment: You're probably running these two pieces of code in different places. Client and Server consoles produce different results with findOne(). Please add more explanation to your question.

Comment: Just checked the console again. The fist submission of var elementObject = myCollection.findOne({elementID: "avatar"}); returns undefined but calling "elementObject" again returns the object.  So it looks it's console display behavior?

Comment: Which console? browser or terminal/server? You need to be specific.

Comment: Browser console to be specific. To clarify, I discovered that the command works but the browser console just didn't return the right thing on the first entry. This question is essentially resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running the second piece of code in console you are just seeing the word undefined and you are thinking that it returned undefined. But actually that is not the case. If the first statement works the second one will also work. 
So after running the second line, just type `elementObject` and press enter in console. Now you will be able to see the actual value assigned to the variable.

Comment: There's a few issues with your answer. First, making answers based on guesses is generally a bad idea, particularly when the question itself is not 100% complete (as said in the comment). Second, "u r", "1st", and the not formatted piece of code `elementObject`. Finally, your answer would rather fit inside a comment, since your solution requires another input from the asker. Please edit/delete it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it does look like I'm seeing "undefined" from the console but that's not actually the case. Typing "elementObject" again returns the document.

Comment: This was essentially what happened, the browser console returned `undefined` on the first try but the variable was actually set.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription is not ready. Your variable doesn´t wait till it gets the result from your query. You have to do something like

```
{{#if YOURHELPER}} template code {{/if}}
```

or use a Iron-Router with waitOn. So that your template gets rendered when everything is there.

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#the-waiton-option

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do have a subscribe function in place and the find() works, I just couldn't do a find and assign at the same time.